# Intellij SVN stopped working after 'Clear Auth Cache'

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

Im using intellij IDEA 14. I cleared Subversion auth cache by **Preferences > Version Control > Subversion > Clear authentication cache**. After this Subversion in intellij is throwing below error. I tried restarting intellij, but it dint work.

```
Subversion: (Accessing URL: https://..) Received fatal alert: handshake_failure Please check Subversion SSL settings (Settings | Version Control | Subversion | Network) Maybe you should specify SSL protocol manually - SSLv3 or TLSv1
```

Anybody knows how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restarted restarted my machine, as restarting intellij did not work. The issue got resolved